# ./sysroot.sh: Operation not permitted

Tags: macos, bash, operation

im trying to install the cydia source code.

```
$ git clone git://git.saurik.com/cydia.git
$ cd cydia
```

but when i typing "./sysroot.sh" i got this error:

```
-bash: ./sysroot.sh: /usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: Operation not permitted
```

what the problem?

Comment: What does sysroot.sh do? did u try run it as a root? does sysroot.sh has 'x' mode?

Comment: what is 'x' mode? sysroot is very big file. give you the code of sysroot.sh?

Comment: show us just few first line, and check if u have `usr/bin/env` program on your `$PATH`

Comment: i dont have usr/bin/env in $PATH.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My guess would be that the filesystem you are trying to run the script from is mounted using the "noexec" option. The interpreter inside of a shebang does not need to be in your $PATH, since an absolute path is specified. Try running your script by calling the interpreter, rather than the script:

```
bash sysroot.sh
```