# Mac OS: /usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: Operation not permitted

Tags: macos, perl, bash, command-line-interface, env

I'm trying to run this script on Mac OS 10.7 (Lion) and I'm getting the error:

```
$ bbcolors
-bash: /usr/local/bin/bbcolors: /usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: Operation not permitted
```

I've successfully run this script on other Macs of mine. It's just [this script](http://daringfireball.net/projects/bbcolors/) downloaded and unmodified from Daring Fireball.

I found [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501063/sysroot-sh-operation-not-permitted) with a very similar problem but the accepted answer was that the filesystem had a 'noexe' option on mount.  I'm pretty sure that's not the case for me because I've just got it in /usr/local/bin/ and other stuff in there works fine (it also doesn't run from other places or as other users including root).

```
$ which bbcolors
/usr/local/bin/bbcolors
$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/bbcolors 
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 nick  staff  9751 Mar 30 19:09 /usr/local/bin/bbcolors
```

It's a Perl script not a compiled binary, not that that should matter.  Here's some extra info for what it's worth:

```
$ cat /usr/local/bin/bbcolors |head -n 1
#!/usr/bin/env perl
$ which perl
/usr/bin/perl
$ env | grep PATH
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

Comment: You've covered most of the normal bases for what might be going wrong; well done.  What happens when you run `perl -v`?  What appears after the initial comment lines in the Perl script (`bbcolors`)?  Also, the `@` after the permissions means there is some auxilliary attribute information for the file; have you investigated that that is (perhaps with `ls -@`)?

Comment: I solved the problem with `xattr -r com.apple.quarantine /file/path`  I will answer my own question but I don't have enough rep to do it for a few hours.

Comment: `xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /usr/local/bin/bbcolors`?  (`-r` means 'recursive'; `-d` means 'delete'.)  I keep forgetting what that command is called.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Did you happen to open/save the file in TextEdit?

That can introduce filesystem metadata (quarantine attribute) [leading to the symptom you describe](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/comp.sys.mac.system/OMuXCAXFWOE).

Try:

```
xattr -l /usr/local/bin/bbcolors
```

and

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /usr/local/bin/bbcolors
```

if you see the quarantine attribute.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't answer my own question, but you've got the right info out of my my comments above.  FWIW: it's also worth doing a `ls -al@` on the file to see the `com.apple.quarantine`.

Comment: Ha.  I found that solution *without* reading your comments.  That'll teach me to refresh more often.

Comment: For reference, if you realize you have a whole directory tree with the `com.apple.quarantine` attribute, run `xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine .` from inside the directory to clean all files within it. I got a mass-quarantined directory like that by unzipping a zip file I had copied over a local network.

Comment: 1000X this! Thanks. My slightly changed solution was `xattr -rd com.apple.quarantine [path to where shit hit the fan]`

Comment: The com.apple.quarantine might also be set on the Disk Image, causing it to be mounted with quarantine.

Comment: For sparse images, I did not find the `com.apple.quarantine` attribute on the sparsebundle itself but it was hiding on a file inside the bundle. The `-r` flag was necessary to clear the attribute.

Comment: When running this through an application environment I'm having error: xattr: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: [file path]. Is there any command I can use to fix this?

Comment: I got the quarantine attribute even though I created the file from the command line with "bbedit filename.sh". Crazy. (Yes, BBEdit is GUI, but it's a dev tool, so I would have expected something more dev-friendly than this trap)

Comment: Ugh, do NOT use textedit. Super annoying "feature".

Answer (score 15):

pilcrow's answer is correct, however I draw your attention to the fact that if you are working with a disk image, the problem can be very confusing, as the com.apple.quarantine attribute seems to be inherited from the disk image file to the files inside (thanks to [febeling at Apple dev forums](https://discussions.apple.com/message/19095813#19095813) for noticing that!).

To solve the problem, you have to remove the quarantine attribute from the disk image:

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /path/to/disk/image
```

and then eject and remount the disk image. Then your files will be clean again.

Comment: If it is a sparse bundle, also check the files inside. E.g. in my case the `token` file inside had the quarantine flag and I had to do:
`xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /path/to/disk_image.sparsebundle/token`

Answer (score 6):

I had resolved this issue.Open the command file with TextEdit then save it.

More Info:[Resolved Operation not permitted](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3733470?start=45&tstart=0)

Answer (score 0):

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/bbcolors: /usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: Operation not permitted
```

Does `/usr/bin/env` exist?  Can you run it?  Run by itself it should dump your environment variables to stdout.

You can safely replace:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
```

With the full path to your `perl` binary of choice, e.g:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

Comment: The advantage of using `#!/usr/bin/env perl` is that it uses your PATH environment instead. So that if you have multiple interpreters on your system, it uses your preferred one.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this after creating a shell script in BBEdit (CLI: `bbedit ~/bin/foo`). It seems that the macOS sandbox security feature automatically quarantines files modified by BBEdit — if the file is executable and is accessed by BBEdit in a certain way.

The fix is easy: Preferences > Application > Allow

https://www.barebones.com/support/bbedit/quarantine.html

Answer (score -1):

1.delete "node_modules" folder
2.npm install

Comment: What makes you think that this question has *anything* to do with Node.js?