# Gensim mallet CalledProcessError: returned non-zero exit status

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook, gensim, mallet

I'm getting an error while trying to access gensims mallet in jupyter notebooks.  I have the specified file 'mallet' in the same folder as my notebook, but cant seem to access it.  I tried routing to it from the C drive but I still get the same error.  Please help :)

```html
import os
from gensim.models.wrappers import LdaMallet

#os.environ.update({'MALLET_HOME':r'C:/Users/new_mallet/mallet-2.0.8/'})

mallet_path = 'mallet' # update this path

ldamallet = gensim.models.wrappers.LdaMallet(mallet_path, corpus=bow_corpus, num_topics=20, id2word=dictionary)

result = (ldamallet.show_topics(num_topics=3, num_words=10,formatted=False))
for each in result:
    print (each)
```

[image: Mallet Error CalledProcessError]

[image]

Comment: Was there any other error output, before the Python stack trace? What if, immediately after getting the error, you try the shown command-line (`mallet import-file ..."`) yourself – is any more info shown?

Comment: @gojomo thank you for reaching out I appreciate it.  I tried the command you listed and I'm still getting the same error :(

Comment: @gojomo In command prompt that command returns 'mallet' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: That suggests that the necessary `mallet` executable either isn't installed, or can't be found from where the Python interpreter, and you when you manually re-try, are executing. Are you sure it's installed? Can you fix your `mallet_path` variable to actually be a valid path to the `mallet` executable?

Comment: @gojomo As far as I can tell mallet is installed though I can't seem to find an executable.  I've even written up path environment variables and tripled checked my path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update the path to:

```
mallet_path = 'C:/mallet/mallet-2.0.8/bin/mallet.bat'
```

and edit the notepad mallet.bat within the mallet 2.0.8 folder to:

```
@echo off

rem This batch file serves as a wrapper for several
rem  MALLET command line tools.

if not "%MALLET_HOME%" == "" goto gotMalletHome

echo MALLET requires an environment variable MALLET_HOME.
goto :eof

:gotMalletHome

set MALLET_CLASSPATH=C:\mallet\mallet-2.0.8\class;C:\mallet\mallet-2.0.8\lib\mallet-deps.jar
set MALLET_MEMORY=1G
set MALLET_ENCODING=UTF-8

set CMD=%1
shift

set CLASS=
if "%CMD%"=="import-dir" set CLASS=cc.mallet.classify.tui.Text2Vectors
if "%CMD%"=="import-file" set CLASS=cc.mallet.classify.tui.Csv2Vectors
if "%CMD%"=="import-svmlight" set CLASS=cc.mallet.classify.tui.SvmLight2Vectors
if "%CMD%"=="info" set CLASS=cc.mallet.classify.tui.Vectors2Info
if "%CMD%"=="train-classifier" set CLASS=cc.mallet.classify.tui.Vectors2Classify
if "%CMD%"=="classify-dir" set CLASS=cc.mallet.classify.tui.Text2Classify
if "%CMD%"=="classify-file" set CLASS=cc.mallet.classify.tui.Csv2Classify
if "%CMD%"=="classify-svmlight" set CLASS=cc.mallet.classify.tui.SvmLight2Classify
if "%CMD%"=="train-topics" set CLASS=cc.mallet.topics.tui.TopicTrainer
if "%CMD%"=="infer-topics" set CLASS=cc.mallet.topics.tui.InferTopics
if "%CMD%"=="evaluate-topics" set CLASS=cc.mallet.topics.tui.EvaluateTopics
if "%CMD%"=="prune" set CLASS=cc.mallet.classify.tui.Vectors2Vectors
if "%CMD%"=="split" set CLASS=cc.mallet.classify.tui.Vectors2Vectors
if "%CMD%"=="bulk-load" set CLASS=cc.mallet.util.BulkLoader
if "%CMD%"=="run" set CLASS=%1 & shift

if not "%CLASS%" == "" goto gotClass

echo Mallet 2.0 commands: 
echo   import-dir        load the contents of a directory into mallet instances (one per file)
echo   import-file       load a single file into mallet instances (one per line)
echo   import-svmlight   load a single SVMLight format data file into mallet instances (one per line)
echo   info              get information about Mallet instances
echo   train-classifier  train a classifier from Mallet data files
echo   classify-dir      classify data from a single file with a saved classifier
echo   classify-file     classify the contents of a directory with a saved classifier
echo   classify-svmlight classify data from a single file in SVMLight format
echo   train-topics      train a topic model from Mallet data files
echo   infer-topics      use a trained topic model to infer topics for new documents
echo   evaluate-topics   estimate the probability of new documents given a trained model
echo   prune             remove features based on frequency or information gain
echo   split             divide data into testing, training, and validation portions
echo   bulk-load         for big input files, efficiently prune vocabulary and import docs
echo Include --help with any option for more information


goto :eof

:gotClass

set MALLET_ARGS=

:getArg

if "%1"=="" goto run
set MALLET_ARGS=%MALLET_ARGS% %1
shift
goto getArg

:run

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12\bin\java" -ea -Dfile.encoding=%MALLET_ENCODING% -classpath %MALLET_CLASSPATH% %CLASS% %MALLET_ARGS%

:eof
```

in command line these were helpful commands to figure out what was going on:

```
notepad mallet.bat
java
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12\bin\java
dir /OD
cd %userdir%
cd %userpath%
cd\
cd users
cd your_username
cd appdata\local\temp\2
dir /OD
```

the problem is with java not being installed correctly or with the path not including java and the mallet classpath not being defined correctly.  More info here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html .  This solved my error hopefully it helps someone else :)

Answer (score 3):

**Make sure you installed the Java Developers Kit ([JDK](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html)).**

The credit goes to [this another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56148576/calledprocesserror-returned-non-zero-exit-status-1)

*After installing the JDK*, the following codes for the LDA Mallet worked like charm!

```
import os
from gensim.models.wrappers import LdaMallet

os.environ.update({'MALLET_HOME':r'C:/mallet/mallet-2.0.8/'})
mallet_path = r'C:/mallet/mallet-2.0.8/bin/mallet.bat'

lda_mallet = LdaMallet(
        mallet_path,
        corpus = corpus_bow,
        num_topics = n_topics,
        id2word = dct,
    )
```

Comment: after installing JDK, did you add it to path? I also have jre and i've added that to JAVA_HOME so not sure if I should keep that or use the JDK path...

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem. What I did was change the location of mallet folder to the c://new_mallet
so it worked nicely

```
    import os
    os.environ.update({'MALLET_HOME': r'C:/new_mallet/mallet-2.0.8/'})
    mallet_path = 'C:/new_mallet/mallet-2.0.8/bin/mallet'  # update this path
    ldamallet = gensim.models.wrappers.LdaMallet(mallet_path, corpus=corpus, num_topics=10, id2word=id2word)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Jupyter Notebook with Python, I run a

```
conda uninstall gensim
conda install gensim
```

in cmd as an administrator and restarted my kernel. Worked like charm after i spent horrendous hours online searching.

Comment: do you recall the versions you switched from and to? I can't seem to get it right with this solution. my gensim version is 3.8.3 as 4.0.1 doesnt have wrapper

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was not an import or a path problem.

I spent hours trying to solve it.
Tried this [solution](https://www.iditect.com/how-to/55288724.html) and nothing worked.

Looking to a previous sucessfull call I made to LDA Mallet, I noticed some parameters were not being set, then I made it like this:

gensim.models.wrappers.LdaMallet(mallet_path=mallet_path, corpus=corpus, num_topics=num_topics, id2word=id2word, prefix='temp_file_', workers=4)

I really hope it helps you. Finding a solution to this problem was a pain.

Answer (score 0):

For linux, I found that one needs to explicitly define the binary mallet path. The following code works.

```
from gensim.test.utils import common_corpus, common_dictionary
from gensim.models.wrappers import LdaMallet

mallet_path = "/path/Mallet/bin/mallet"
model = LdaMallet(mallet_path=mallet_path, corpus=common_corpus, num_topics=2, id2word=common_dictionary)
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who is still struggling and spent hours trying many different suggestions, I finally got it working!

follow the instructions here (I was on mac)

https://ps.au.dk/fileadmin/ingen_mappe_valgt/installing_mallet.pdf

I also closed anaconda before I started this, don't know if that's important.

In the terminal I got the following error:

```
(base) myname-MacBook-Air:mallet-2.0.8 myname$ ./bin/mallet
-bash: ./bin/mallet: /bin/bash: bad interpreter: Operation not permitted
```

then I followed these instructions to un-quarantine

[“bad interpreter: Operation not permitted” Error on El Capitan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37740411/bad-interpreter-operation-not-permitted-error-on-el-capitan)

reopened anaconda and it all worked!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Here, no one should have to follow links to get the answer that they need.  Put all of the steps and code **in your answer**.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed the issue by downloading JDK java https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/install/installation-jdk-macos.html#GUID-F9183C70-2E96-40F4-9104-F3814A5A331F

Comment: don't know how but it just works like this user shared too https://stackoverflow.com/a/64695204/15564570

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error because I had forgotten to install java on my ubuntu.