# How to fix mallet on gensim

Tags: gensim, lda, kaggle, mallet

I wrote LDA model in notebook.
I'm trying to wrap my gensim LDA model with mallet, getting the following error:

CalledProcessError: Command '../input/mymallet/mallet-2.0.8/bin/mallet import-file --preserve-case --keep-sequence --remove-stopwords --token-regex "\S+" --input /tmp/fbcc4b_corpus.txt --output /tmp/fbcc4b_corpus.mallet' returned non-zero exit status 126.

The error raised because of the second line:

```
mallet_path = '../input/mymallet/mallet-2.0.8/bin/mallet' # update this path
ldamallet = gensim.models.wrappers.LdaMallet(mallet_path, corpus=corpus, num_topics=20, id2word=id2word)
```

The path is correct.

Tried this solution:  [Gensim mallet CalledProcessError: returned non-zero exit status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55288724/gensim-mallet-calledprocesserror-returned-non-zero-exit-status)

didn't work for me..

Answer (score 0):

I spent hours trying to solve it.
Tried this [solution](https://www.iditect.com/how-to/55288724.html) and nothing worked.

Looking to a previous sucessfull call I made to LDA Mallet, I noticed some parameters were not being set, then I made it like this:

gensim.models.wrappers.LdaMallet(mallet_path=mallet_path, corpus=corpus, num_topics=num_topics, id2word=id2word, prefix='temp_file_', workers=4)

I really hope it helps you. Finding a solution to this problem is a pain.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you ever solved this or not, but I have run into the same problem.  For me, the problem occurred because I had uploaded the mallet binary to a research server, where Mallet lost its executable flag.  My solution was to run

`chmod -R +x mallet-2.0.8`

This allowed the gensim wrapper, or whatever means you wish to run mallet, to run the executable file.  If you want to be more precise with the `chmod`, you could probably `chmod` the actual `mallet-2.0.8/bin/mallet` file.