# cannot install homebrew on macos sierra

Tags: homebrew

I am running this command:
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

and I'm get hte error:

```
HEAD is now at 79e8cdd Merge pull request #1253 from jawshooah/perf/relocate-text-files
/usr/local/bin/brew: /usr/local/bin/readlink: /bin/bash: bad interpreter: Operation not permitted
/usr/local/bin/brew: /usr/local/bin/readlink: /bin/bash: bad interpreter: Operation not permitted
/usr/local/bin/brew: line 47: /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/brew.sh: No such file or directory
Failed during: /usr/local/bin/brew update --force
```

[Does any one know how to solve this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4loaX.jpg)

Comment: You'd better find and post the exact code that's giving the error. Otherwise, you'll have better luck in another forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's maybe related to filesystem metadata (quarantine attribute), run:

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin
```

If you see a `@` character on some lines such as in `-rwxr-xr-x@`, you can remove the filesystem metadata with :

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /usr/local/bin/readlink
```

Read this question for more information :
[Mac OS: /usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: Operation not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952612/mac-os-usr-bin-env-bad-interpreter-operation-not-permitted)

Answer (score 0):

Just because I came across this answer in my search for how to fix this problem, and the accepted answer didn't work for me, I figured I would post my solution. After reinstalling brew a million different ways (which had issues due to the readlink problem), reinstalling ruby, xcode-tools, and every other piece of software on the planet, I had the "duhh" moment of trying to see what was wrong with `readlink` itself.

In the end, this is how I fixed it:

1. `cd /usr/local/bin`
2. `rm readlink`
3. Make a file called `realpath` (or whatever you want) with this content

here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os,sys
print os.path.realpath(sys.argv[1])
```

4. `chmod +x realpath`
5. `ln -s realpath readlink`

The above instructions can be found [here.](https://gist.github.com/esycat/5279354) Essentially we're just replacing whatever `readlink` they had implemented originally with Python's implementation of the functionality, their `os.path.realpath` function.