# Why I take "spark-shell: Permission denied" error in Spark Setup?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs, spark-shell

I am new on Apache Spark. I am trying to setup Apache Spark to my Macbook. 
 I download file "spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7" from Apache Spark official web site.
When I try to run ./bin/spark-shell or ./bin/pyspark I get `Permission denied error`.
I want to just run spark on my local machine.
I also tried to give permission to all folders but it does not help.
Why do I this error?

Comment: Have you tried `chmod +x`

Comment: After chmod +x spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7  I take this for pyspark =>
/Users/apple/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit: line 27: /Users/apple/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class: Permission denied
/Users/apple/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit: line 27: exec: /Users/apple/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class: cannot execute: Undefined error: 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solve this issue by adding **/libexec** folder to spark home path

set $**SPARK_HOME** to

/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/<your_spark_version>/libexec

Answer (score 4):

This should solve your problem `chmod +x /Users/apple/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/*`

Then you could try executing `bin/pyspark` (spark shell in python) or `bin/spark-shell` (spark shell in scala).

Comment: I tried  but i take still take same errors for spark-shell and pyspark=> chmod +x /Users/apple/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/*
-bash: ./bin/spark-shell: /usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: Operation not permitted
apple-MacBook-Air:spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7 apple$ ./bin/pyspark
/Users/apple/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit: /Users/apple/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class: /usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: Operation not permitted
/Users/apple/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit: line 27: /Users/apple/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-class: Undefined error: 0

Comment: Have you opened the files with an editor? In that case, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952612/mac-os-usr-bin-env-bad-interpreter-operation-not-permitted