# Git hooks: '.git/hooks/pre-commit': Operation not permitted

Tags: bash, git, githooks, macos-mojave

This is all on OS X Mojave.

I’m trying to block myself from mistakenly making commits to the master branch, because that is a thing I do a little too often, using [the `pre-commit` Git hook from this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40465455/475818), changed slightly because I use bash instead of sh.  Every time I tried to run it, though, I got the following:

```
fatal: cannot exec '.git/hooks/pre-commit': Operation not permitted
```

I checked the permissions of the `.git` and `.git/hooks` directories.  Both are `drwxrwxrwx`.  The permissions on `pre-commit` itself are:

```
-rwxr-xr-x@  1 emeyer  staff    25 Feb  5 11:50 pre-commit
```

…which is the same as the `pre-commit.sample` file I copied over to `pre-commit` and then replaced the contents.  I tried `chmod +w` but that didn’t fix it.

I decided to simplify my testing and replaced the contents of `pre-commit` with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Test"
```

I still got the above-referenced `Operation not permitted` error.  I also tried it with `#!/bin/sh` like in the SO answer’s example; same result.

If I try running the script directly, by typing `./pre-commit` from the command line, I get a slightly different error: `-bash: ./pre-commit: /bin/bash: bad interpreter: Operation not permitted`.  The error is consistent whether I use `/bin/bash`, `/bin/sh`, `/usr/local/bin/bash`, or `/usr/local/bin/sh`.

Googling, Binging, and SO-searching didn’t get me an answer that worked, so I’m asking here how to allow the operation, or whatever is needed.

Comment: Is your git repository on a filesystem that is mounted with the `noexec` option?

Comment: Are you using MacOS? (The `@` suggests that you are.) You're probably hitting the System Integrity Protection feature in Mojave.

Comment: It is in fact OS X Mojave!  I tried running `pre-commit` directly and got `-bash: ./pre-commit: /bin/bash: bad interpreter: Operation not permitted` (and the same basic result with `sh`),

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `pre-commit` file may have file metadata associated with it (the `@` in your `ls` output suggests this), and that that file metadata may include the com.apple.quarantine attribute.

You should be able to confirm this using the following:

`ls -l@ pre-commit`

or

`xattr -l pre-commit`

And you should be able to remove the attribute with:

`xattr -d com.apple.quarantine pre-commit`

ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9952742/157515

Comment: That’s it!  Thank you!

Comment: Also, today I learned what the `@` meant in `ls`, so thank you twice!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following commands:

1. `chmod +x .git-hooks/pre-push`
   where `.git-hooks/pre-push` is your directory with already configured hooks.
2. `ln -s -f ../../.git-hooks/pre-push .git/hooks/pre-push`
   The `.git-hooks/pre-push` directory already has the access permissions that were configured in the previous command